# How to save and display images with Picasso

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, picasso

I'm not too familiar with Picasso, but my app uses it to load images from their URL.
But I want to make a button which when it's clicked, it would mark the image as favorite, displaying it even when it's offline.
I'm saving the other stuff (strings, doubles) with a Content Provider.

So, I think the best way to accomplish this is saving the image to display even offline.
But how to I save them?

Answer (score 0):

There is another good choice for downloading Image with url. Try for this code .

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new DownloadFile().execute("https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4kCo.jpg");
}
class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Long> {
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);// Change Mainactivity.this with your activity name. 
    String strFolderName;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading Image ...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL((String) aurl[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();
            String targetFileName="downloadedimage.jpg";//Change name and subname

            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myImage/";
            File folder = new File(PATH);
            if(!folder.exists()){
                folder.mkdir();//If there is no folder it will be created.
            }
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(PATH+targetFileName);
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                       publishProgress ((int)(total*100/lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return null;
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
         if(mProgressDialog.getProgress()==mProgressDialog.getMax()){
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download Completed !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         }
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    }
}
```

And set downloaded image bitmap to Imageview .

Answer (score 0):

This is code. By this strategy Picasso will look for images in cache and if it failed only then image will be downloaded over network.

```
     Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(Uri.parse(getItem(position).getStoryBigThumbUrl()))
                        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                        .into(holder.storyBigThumb, new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError() {
                                // Try again online if cache failed
                                Picasso.with(context)
                                        .load(Uri.parse(getItem(position)
                                                .getStoryBigThumbUrl()))
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
                                .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
                                        .into(holder.storyBigThumb);
                            }
                        });
```

Picasso have its own cache you wont be need to handle anything on your own.